# CNTK CMD RedirectStandardOutput = true not working

Tags: c#, cntk

Microsoft have dropped CNTK for ML.NET ( Horrible product ) and ONNX ( Not yet looked at it ).

CNTK, best product Microsoft have Open Sourced, but lots of Bugs and Zero Support, sadly!

I reluctantly look toward the Stackoverflow community for a potential resolution.

```
string filepath = @"<My big long Path>\";
string filename = Path.Combine(filepath, @"Data\SLUHandsOn.cntk");

if (!File.Exists(filename))
    ProcessOutputData("File does not exist!");

Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = filepath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c cntk configFile=" + "\"" + filename + "\"";

process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process.Start();

process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((x, y) =>
{
    ProcessOutputData(y.Data);
});

process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

The Method `ProcessOutputData` is pretty simple also:

```
private void ProcessOutputData(string text)
{

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { ProcessOutputData(text); }));
    }
    else
    {
        // Output Data:
        richTextBox1.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Needless to say, CNTK appears to Output no Data. I have tried running CNTK with both CMD.exe and using the CNTK.exe from [Visual Studio Tools for AI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.vstoolsai-vs2017&ssr=false#overview) Redistributable.

Again, the problem I am facing is there is no `RedirectStandardOutput` data.

Thank You.

**ANSWER** Credit to: MarcelGrommer - Thank You!

```
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{

    ProcessOutputData(e.Data);
});

// Asynchronously read the standard Error of the spawned process.
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the RedirectStandardError channel. CNTK calculates the network error, so the data comes on the StandardError channel. It works.

```
processCNTK.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
            string outFromCNTK = e.Data;
}
```